# About lineargradient in android

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

I want to achieve a `LinearGradient` effect in `SurfaceView`, but the display is not smooth. It shows some lines on the screen. Is the display itself the reason?  Here's my code:

```
    try {    
        canvas = sfh.lockCanvas(); 
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT,Mode.CLEAR);
        paint = new Paint();   
        linearGradient = new LinearGradient(0,0,0,ScreenH,new int[]{Color.argb(230,255,200, 236),Color.argb(200,255, 153,153)},null,TileMode.CLAMP); 

        paint.setShader(linearGradient);  
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);

    } catch (Exception ex) {    
    } finally {     
        if (canvas != null)    
            sfh.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following to make it smooth,

```
getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
```

Comment: OMG. Thanks a lot!